# Timestamp to string date

Tags: android, date, timestamp

I don't know how to transform timestamp to date.
I have:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView czas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String S = "1350574775";
    czas.setText(getDate(S));        
}



private String getDate(String timeStampStr){
   try{
       DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
       Date netDate = (new Date(Long.parseLong(timeStampStr)));
       return sdf.format(netDate);
   } catch (Exception ignored) {
    return "xx";
   }
}
```

And answer is: 01/16/1970, but it is wrong.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

try this if you're sticking with "1350574775" format which is in seconds:

```
private void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    ....
    String S = "1350574775";

    //convert unix epoch timestamp (seconds) to milliseconds
    long timestamp = Long.parseLong(s) * 1000L; 
    czas.setText(getDate(timestamp ));  
}



private String getDate(long timeStamp){

    try{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return sdf.format(netDate);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        return "xx";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this answer solved my problem. but how to get this date 

in this format

22 Jul 2017

Comment: Works like a charm. Kudos

Answer (score 6):

```
String S = "1350574775";
```

You are sending your timestamp in seconds, instead of milliseconds.

Do this, instead:

```
String S = "1350574775000";
```

**Or**, in your `getDate` method, multiply by `1000L`:

```
new Date(Long.parseLong(timeStampStr) * 1000L)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String getTime(long timeStamp){
    try{
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp * 1000);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        Date date = (Date) calendar.getTime();
        return sdf.format(date);
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return "";
}
```