# How to sort timestamp list?

Tags: java, android, sorting, date, timestamp

I have a list of timestamp(long) in which I have to sort list base on time or list added.

I have tried and searched but its now working.

```
 Collections.sort(vehicles, new Comparator<VehicleListModel.Vehicle>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(VehicleListModel.Vehicle o1, VehicleListModel.Vehicle o2) {
                    try {
                        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                        return format.parse(o1.getCreated()).compareTo(format.parse(o2.getCreated()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            });
            customerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

its not working then I tried
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241251/timestamp-to-string-date) but this `Date(timeStamp)` is deprecated

please help

Comment: ***i have tried and searched but its now working*** this is not enough for us to helping you! **HOW** is not working?

Comment: what is this string here: getCreated()????

Comment: getCreated() return timestamp of row added to service now i have to sort based on the timestamp

Comment: What is the return type of `getCreated()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `getCreated` returns a `Date` then you can compare two dates using `compareTo` and sort the list based on this comparison, e.g.:

```
List<VehicleListModel.Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.sort((e1, e2) -> e1.getCreated().compareTo(e2.getCreated()));
```

**update**

If `getCreated` returns `long` value then you can box it and use `compareTo` method of `Long` class, e.g.:

```
List<ChainCode> list = new ArrayList<ChainCode>();
list.sort((e1, e2) -> new Long(e1.getCreated()).compareTo(new Long(e2.getCreated())));
```

Comment: sir,  
getCreated() return timestamp of row added to service now i have to sort based on the timestamp

Comment: @KRoy do you mean `java.sql.Timestamp` or just a `long` value?

Comment: long value! @Darshan

Comment: simply sorting it based on long value?

Comment: Yes, they are timestamps so you don't need to worry about anything else (e.g. dates etc) try this and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: it worked! but here you used Lamda Exp. but i did   Collections.sort(vehicles, new Comparator<VehicleListModel.Vehicle>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(VehicleListModel.Vehicle o1, VehicleListModel.Vehicle o2) {
                        try {
                            return o2.getCreated().compareTo(o1.getCreated());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                });

Comment: Simpler and better: `list.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(e -> e.getCreated());`.

Answer (score 1):

Use long timestamp value for soring

```
     Collections.sort(vehicles, new Comparator<VehicleListModel.Vehicle>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(VehicleListModel.Vehicle o1, VehicleListModel.Vehicle o2) {
                        try {
                            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
return Long.valueOf(format.parse(o1.getCreated()).getTime()).compareTo(format.parse(o2.getCreated()).getTime());

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
                customerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Date is comparable, so this shouldn't change much.

Comment: getCreated() return timestamp of row added to service now i have to sort based on the timestamp in long